# Adobe flash exceeding time span due to heavy effects and shapes ? any solution pls

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript, 2d, adobe

I m doing a small animation project of 15 seconds in Adobe Flash CS6. But due to heavy shapes and effects (emboss, blur, drop shadow with clip mask, opacity mask, only 3 images etc), i m getting the output file more then 15 seconds long and animation also not smooth. The shapes i m designing in Adobe illustrator and importing to Flash.

After removing some layers i m getting the 15 seconds ok output.

Pls any one guide to optimize the time of my animation.

Comment: What is your output format?  swf?  video file?

Comment: .swf or the .EXE . Because i hv used AS2 script inside for Full screen.

Comment: Ok.  Vectors are very slow.  First thing to try, is select cacheAsBitmap` on the parent movieClip of all your complex vectors. Only animate movie clips with cacheAsBitmap on, convert your shape to movie clip if need be.  Make sure you export with GPU acceleration on in the publish settings (Hardware Acceleration drop down box).    Filters are very expensive too, especially on large objects, drop anything you don't really need or use low quality

Comment: Thank u sir, i m trying.
Sir, my flash stage area is HD (1920x 1080). I hv used only 3 images only, but my client needs HD images. 
so may it affect my 15 second target of timeline ?
or i hv to follow that same "Render : Cash as Btimap" and "GPU Acceleration" for images also ?

Comment: The GPU acceleration is global. so you set it for the entire SWF.   Yes, HD resolution it's especially important to cache complex vectors as bitmap